# Get relationship type in a php variable of neo4j

Tags: neo4j, neo4jphp

What I want is that: I have two nodes with id 1 and id 2. It has a relationship type `(id:1)-[r:Knows]->(id:2)`. My query is working fine in Neo4j as localhost but I am not able to store that relationship type in a PHP variable to use further. I am using graphware.

**Note: $id = 1  and  $s_id = 2.**

```
$queryString = "MATCH (a:signup{iid:'$id'})-[r]->(b:signup{iid:'$s_id'}) return type(r) ";

$query = new Everyman\Neo4j\Cypher\Query($client, $queryString);

$result = $query->getResultSet();

if($result == 'Knows')
{
    $s_relation = $result;
}
else
{
    $s_relation = 'empty';
}
```

It returns the else part as EMPTY.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a solution for this.